# Minimizing the sum of absolute values with a linear solver

Tags: linear-programming, absolute-value

I need a linear program to minimize the sum of several absolute values, but the inclusion of an absolute value means the linear solver won't work. I know there are ways around using an absolute value, but none of the fixes I've seen apply when you're trying to minimize a *sum* of several absolute values.

Specifically, I have 3 *sets* of constants ($a_1, a2,\ldots$; $\ b_1, b_2,\ldots$; & $\ c_1, c_2,\ldots$) and 2 variables ($x$ & $y$). The gist of my program is below.

$$\min (|a_1 x + b_1 y - c_1| + |a_2 x + b_2 y - c_2| + |a_3 x + b_3 y - c_3|)$$

such that

$$x + y = 1$$

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can introduce new variables $t_i$ and constraints $t_i \geq a_i x + b_i y - c_i$ and $t_i \geq -(a_i x + b_i y - c_i)$, and then minimize $\sum_i t_i$ subject to the new constraints and your additional constraints.

Comment: This seems to solve the problem. Thank you!

Comment: don't you also need $t_i\geq 0$ ?

Comment: @DimaPasechnik The constraints I mentioned already imply that $t_i \geq 0$.

Comment: ah, right. I was being silly, sorry.

Answer (score 10):

This is really a comment on littlO's answer. Comment box is too small for this.
$$
\min (|a_1 x + b_1 y - c_1| + |a_2 x + b_2 y - c_2| + |a_3 x + b_3 y - c_3|), x+y = 1$$
is equivalent to
$$
\min t_1 + t_2 + t_3  
\text{ such that} \\
a_1 x + b_1 y -c_1 \le t_1 \\
a_1 x + b_1 y -c_1 \ge -t_1 \\
a_2 x + b_2 y -c_2 \le t_2\\
a_2 x + b_2 y -c_2 \ge -t_2 \\
a_3 x + b_3 y -c_3 \le t_3 \\
a_3 x + b_3 y -c_3 \ge -t_3 \\
x+y = 1
$$
This just expands on littleO's answer. Please give littleO the credit.

Edited: (typo revised) from: $$a_3 x + b_3 y -c_3 \le t_1 \\$$ to: $$a_3 x + b_3 y -c_3 \le t_3 \\$$