# LP: New way of minimizing sum of absolute values

Tags: linear-programming

### Original Optimization:

Let say I want to **minimize** below function:

> **minimize**
>
> $\left|a_1x_1+a_2x_2-c_1\right| + \left|b_1x_1+b_2x_2-c_2\right|$
>
> **subject to:**
>
> > $x_1^{lower} \le x_1 \le x_1^{upper}$
> >
> > $x_2^{lower} \le x_2 \le x_2^{upper}$

**Solutions online**: I have seen that the proposed solutions are mainly to introduce an auxiliary variables $t_1$ and $t_2$, and try to **minimize** $(t_1 + t_2)$ subject to some constraints around $t_1$ and $t_2$ values. (e.g. this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/623568/minimizing-the-sum-of-absolute-values-with-a-linear-solver)).

### Can below Linear Programming reformulation work?

But here is another possibility with seems simpler and effective. I am not sure what am I missing and why nobody has suggested this:

> **maximize**
>
> $a_1x_1+a_2x_2 + b_1x_1+b_2x_2$
>
> **subject to:**
>
> > $a_1x_1+a_2x_2 \le c_1$
> >
> > $b_1x_1+b_2x_2 \le c_2$
> >
> > $x_1^{lower} \le x_1 \le x_1^{upper}$
> >
> > $x_2^{lower} \le x_2 \le x_2^{upper}$

Comment: Why would you assume that the expressions within the absolute values are negative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't. Let's consider an extreme case where 
$$\min |x_1 +x_2 - 1|+ |x_1 +x_2 - 1|$$

$$1 \le x_1 \le 1$$

$$1 \le x_2 \le 1$$

which is feasible.

Your method would construct the following feasible set.

$$x_1 + x_2 \le 1$$
$$x_1 + x_2 \le 1$$
$$1 \le x_1 \le 1$$

$$1 \le x_2 \le 1$$

which is not feasible.

Comment: Interesting example. So it the $t_1$ and $t_2$ solution which I linked to from another post the only possibility ?

Comment: To claim that something is the only way to do something is a very bold statement. I welcome new ideas unless it's proven that that's the only way.